# Use of a one-way hash without a salt while fixing Download of code without Integrity check issue Checkmarx

Tags: java, spring, security, password-hash, checkmarx

I am trying to load some library ".so" / ".dll" files using below code

```
System.load("some file");
```

then after performing Static application security testing (SAST) using **checkmarx** tool
it is complaining Download of Code Without Integrity Check issue.

then I tried to fix the **Download of Code Without Integrity Check** SAST issue using checksum

I generated a library file checksum using a sha-512 algorithm and kept it in a String constant

```
 public static final String TRUSTED_SHA512 = "12af30d9ffc1cdd85d21e73c8c81b7c379a9b4ab2ea5676cd9d232788e2b44fbab876796104f37d0f6a5f7bc5f97eb3663e432785b94039b5320bbfac3d19516";
```

now before loading the file, I am computing hash again with the same algorithm and checking it against String constant **TRUSTED_SHA512**

```
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        String sha512ofQrcToolsWrapper = ChecksumHelper.getFileChecksum(md,temp);
        if(sha512ofQrcToolsWrapper.equalsIgnoreCase(ServiceConstants.TRUSTED_SHA512_OF_QRCTOOLSWRAPPER)) {
            System.load(temp.getAbsolutePath());
        }else{
            throw new Exception("failed to load windows dll file : Checksum mismatched");
        }
```

Now checkmarx tool is giving **one more issue Use of a one-way hash without a salt**
then i updated message digest with static salt value. The
reason behind using fix salt value instead of random value is that we want to compute same hash at runtime to check with the one already there in constant

```
 public static String getFileChecksum(MessageDigest digest, File file) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    //Get file input stream for reading the file content
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    //Create byte array to read data in chunks
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
    int bytesCount = 0;

    //Read file data and update in message digest
    while ((bytesCount = fis.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
        digest.update(byteArray, 0, bytesCount);
    }

    //Static salt value
    digest.update(getSalt());
    
    //close the stream; We don't need it now.
    fis.close();

    //Get the hash's bytes
    byte[] bytes = digest.digest();

    //This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
    //Convert it to hexadecimal format
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    //return complete hash
    return sb.toString();
}
```

NOTE "getSalt() method is returning byte array with fixed values"

Still, checkmarx SAST is complaining both the issues

1. Download of code without Integrity check
2. Use of a one-way hash without a salt

please provide solution to fix these issues. let me know if anything else needed to clarify.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your code should have worked. My theory is that Checkmarx is not able to traverse to your helper method ChecksumHelper.getFileChecksum and create a data flow. Definitely not ideal, but try moving the body of your helper method out into the main code where there is a checksum validation

Comment: Thanks, @RomanCanlas I tried it out but it didn't work still facing the same issue